# Error: Could not find or load main class, but works when .jar is missing from classpath?

Tags: java, selenium, terminal, javac

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlY_6N98WWs&list=PLIBI8eaaUGfSupVFlMBefGodvWQ9ydq51&index=4
And got this error:

```
$ java -classpath selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar HelloWorld 
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
```

But if I run `$ java HelloWorld`, it works just fine, and says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver at 
HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:13) Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.j
```

I’m on Mac terminal, and I tried with `CLASSPATH`s of `.` and blank. My `$PATH` variable is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin` and seems to be fine.

I tried looking at these pages for the solution: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top)

And it seems like my class path is working fine, but something else is glitchy?

**HelloWorld.java**

```
/**
 * Import FirefoxDriver and By from selenium jar
 */
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{

        // Create a Firefox browser instance
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // Navigate to google home page
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

        // Type hello world in the search field
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello World");

        // Wait for 10 seconds
        Thread.sleep(10*1000);

        // Close the browser instance
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

**Selenium Standalone Server version 3.11.0 downloaded from:**
https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

I'm running on Mac OS 10.13.3.

Comment: Try this: `java -classpath .:selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I needed to append the current directory to the class path by appending `:.` to `selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar`.

```
$ java -classpath selenium-server-standalone-3.11.0.jar:. HelloWorld
```

Special thanks to lanoxx's comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/2423194 that helped me:

> I had this problem when I was trying to run a Class with a 3rd party
>   library. I invoked java like this: java -cp ../third-party-library.jar
>   com.my.package.MyClass; this does not work, instead it is necessary to
>   add the local folder to the class path as well (separated by :, like
>   this: java -cp ../third-party-library.jar:. com.my.package.MyClass,
>   then it should work

and also thanks to Sam Orozco for commenting the answer later while I was typing this up.